# How to use Coq as calculator or as forward chaining rule engine/sequence application tool?

Tags: logic, sequence, coq

Is it possible and how to use Coq as calculator or as rule engine in foward chaining mode? Coq script usually requires to declare the goal for which the proof can be found. But is it possible to go in other direction, e.g. to compute the set of some consequences bounded by some rule, e.g., by some number of steps. I am especially interested in the sequent calculus of full first order logic. I guess (but I don't know) that there are some implementation or package for some type of sequent calculus for first order logic, but it is for theorem proving. I woul like to use such sequent calculus to derive consequences in some directed order. Is that possible in Coq and how?

Answer (score 1):

Coq can be used for forward reasoning as well, in particular with the `assert` tactic.  When you write `assert (H : P).`, Coq generates a subgoal that asks you to prove `P`. When this goal is complete, it resumes the original proof, extending its context with a hypothesis `H : P`.

The ltac language used to write Coq scripts has a `match goal` operator that allows you to inspect the shape of your goal.  This allows you to progressively saturate your proof context with new facts derived from your current assumptions using the `assert` tactic, and to stop once certain conditions are met. Adam Chlipala's CPDT book has a [nice chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Match.html) covering these features of tactic programming.

Comment: Many thanks for suggestion, but I am still confused. assert(H:P) means that I should know the goal (or subgoal H:P) beforehand, that is fine for theorem proving. But in the case of forward reasoning I have no idea what will come up, what will be derived in the next step. Forward reasoning can be used in the cases when I have the aim to deduce some (any or of some value) knowledge about some concept or relation and I have no idea in what form and what those theorems will be, so, I can not express them as some goal. I don't even know whether such theorems will exist.

Comment: http://cll.stanford.edu/~langley/papers/icarus.rrl.ilp05.pdf is article how relational (symbolic) reinforcement learning guides/focuses forward inference in discovering only some knowledge, only valuable/interesting knowledge. I guess that is quite innovative article/approach and before that there were no value in forward reasoning. But now this approach is emerging.

Comment: Isabelle/HOL https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf has chapter 6.2.3 about forward chaining, I am still studying it.